# Codeigniter redirect not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why isn't redirect working here. I'm getting call to undefined function redirect().

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('login_view');        

    }

    function authenticate() {

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $query = $this->user_model->authenticate();

        if($query) {

            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('/site/news_feed');

        }
        else {

            $this->index();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the top portion above your `authenticate()` method to this...

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        // this is your constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //this is only called when someone does not specify a method...
        $this->load->view('login_view');        
    }
...
```

I would strongly recommend moving these two helpers to be autoloaded because of their almost manditory use...

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

If your server is windows, try:

```
redirect('/site/news_feed','refresh');
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not loading the `URL` helper in the `authenticate` method. You'll have to either add `$this->load->helper('URL')` to the class constructor (which it looks like you were trying to do), or you'll have to add that to the authenticate method itself.

Just a reminder, the `index` method is a special method -- it is called when no other method is specified. With the URL `<your domain>/login/`, index will be fired. Other than that, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is inda right but, there are a couple of shortcomings when you load some helpers and models in the constructor **sometimes**.

Try to load the helper from within the function.

Comment: examples of these "shortcomings" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

before your redirect function.

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect() belong to url helper.
```

You can load it like this each time you need it.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

or better to load it globally so you don't need to load it again and again

```
//application/config/autoload.php
$autoload['helper'] = array("url");
```